# Can I hide the path in php error using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, path

Can I hide the path in php error using .htaccess

Example:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hello in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\index.php on line 3
```

I want to hide the path using .htaccess or print something let me know if there is an error without print the path of the page:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hello on line 3
```

or

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hello
```

or

```
There is error in your page
```

## Edit :

I put this lines in my .htaccess
But I can't access to my site. There is error "Internal Server Error"
How Can I fix that

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

Comment: You should not show such error messages to your visitors at all! They are only meant for developers.

Comment: What is the context? You should not output errors/warnings from the PHP interpreter at all. If there such a message, you have to fix your script.

Comment: Do you run PHP as a module and do you have “`AllowOverride Options`” or “`AllowOverride All`” privileges? Otherwise you can’t use [`php_flag` and `php_value`](http://php.net/configuration.changes).

Comment: @Gumbo he does. otherwise he will see no such error.

Comment: I can not understand your question because I do not have much experience in this area :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Hm, you’re right, at least for the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PHP’s error messages are not meant for users but for developers only.**

So for a production environment, you should disable [*display_errors*](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to avoid information disclosure:

> **Note**: [*display_errors*] is a feature to support your development and should never be used on production systems (e.g. systems connected to the internet).

Instead, you should show generic error messages to your users that do not unveil anything of the internals and only log the error messages (see [*log_errors*](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) and [*error_log*](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)):

> **Note**: You're strongly advised to use error logging in place of error displaying on production web sites.

And if you really want to modify PHP’s error messages, you can use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) to set a custom error handler.

See also [*OWASP’s Development Guide* on “Error Handling, Auditing and Logging”](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Error_Handling,_Auditing_and_Logging) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the messages : those are generated by PHP, and that's the way they are.

But you can prevent them from being displayed to your website's users -- and still log them, for your own usage.

For that, see :

- [**`display_errors`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) : to prevent errors from being displayed to the page's output
- [**`log_errors`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) : to indicate that errors should be logged to a file
- [**`error_log`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) : to specify to which file errors will be logged to.

Of course, that doesn't prevent you from fixing as many causes of notices / warnings / errors as possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all that useless stuff.

```
php_flag display_errors 0
```

alone will be enough.

If error persists, check server's error_log for the error message