# Remove C:\inetput\... from php errors

Tags: php, error-handling, config, filepath

How would I remove part of the directory path before my actual php script when showing php errors?

For instance:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load system boot file' in C:\inetpub\Ruby\public_html\websites\local\index.php:8
```

I would rather have it show only this path: `..\websites\local\index.php:8` (in addition to the rest of the error message of course).

I realize I should not show these errors on a public or non-development server, but I would like to increase readability of these errors during development.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605512/can-i-hide-the-path-in-php-error-using-htaccess. The accepted answer sums up the idea that users should never see errors and that custom error handling is available. I'm just not sure how helpful it would be.

Comment: @sealz Had a glance at that question, and the **You cannot change the messages : those are generated by PHP, and that's the way they are.** answer, if correct, ends the discussion. Got my own error handlers to handle most errors, so this is just an attempt to make my development more convenient.